# Why am I getting driver.c(40) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'PDRIVER_OBJECT'

Tags: c

Here's the source of driver.c and lectouch.h which is included just prior to the error.  I've looked at the header for ages and can't spot the error!

This is happening trying to build a WiIndows Driver:

C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\Bin\x86\oacr\oacrcl @c:\source\lectouch\objfre_win7_x86\i386\cl.rsp
1>Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.207 for 80x86
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Here's the header file lectouch.h that driver.c includes just before the first error:

```
/*++

Copyright (c) David C. Partridge.  All rights reserved.

Module Name:

    lectouch.h
    
Abstract:

    common header file

Author:


Environment:

    kernel mode only

Notes:


Revision History:


--*/
#ifndef _LECTOUCH_H_

#define _LECTOUCH_H_

#pragma warning(disable:4200)  // suppress nameless struct/union warning
#pragma warning(disable:4201)  // suppress nameless struct/union warning
#pragma warning(disable:4214)  // suppress bit field types other than int warning
#include <initguid.h>
#include <wdm.h>
#include "usbdi.h"
#include "usbdlib.h"

#pragma warning(default:4200)
#pragma warning(default:4201)
#pragma warning(default:4214)
#include <wdf.h>
#include "wdfusb.h"

#pragma warning(disable:4201)  // suppress nameless struct/union warning
#pragma warning(disable:4214)  // suppress bit field types other than int warning
#include <hidport.h>

#define NTSTRSAFE_LIB
#include <ntstrsafe.h>

typedef UCHAR HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR, *PHID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION{

    //
    //WDF handles for USB Target 
    //
    WDFUSBDEVICE      UsbDevice;

    WDFIOTARGET TargetToSendRequestsTo; 

    LONG LastX;
    LONG LastY;
    BOOLEAN RecentChange;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, * PDEVICE_EXTENSION;

WDF_DECLARE_CONTEXT_TYPE_WITH_NAME(DEVICE_EXTENSION, GetDeviceContext)

//
// driver routine declarations
//
// This type of function declaration is for Prefast for drivers. 
// Because this declaration specifies the function type, PREfast for Drivers
// does not need to infer the type or to report an inference. The declaration
// also prevents PREfast for Drivers from misinterpreting the function type 
// and applying inappropriate rules to the function. For example, PREfast for
// Drivers would not apply rules for completion routines to functions of type
// DRIVER_CANCEL. The preferred way to avoid Warning 28101 is to declare the
// function type explicitly. In the following example, the DriverEntry function
// is declared to be of type DRIVER_INITIALIZE.
//
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD HidFx2EvtDeviceAdd;

EVT_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL HidFx2EvtInternalDeviceControl;

EVT_WDF_OBJECT_CONTEXT_CLEANUP HidFx2EvtDriverContextCleanup;

#endif   //_LECTOUCH_H_
```

and the driver.c

```
/*++

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
    KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE
    IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
    PURPOSE.

Module Name:

    driver.c

Abstract:

    Code for main entry point of KMDF driver

Author:


Environment:

    kernel mode only

Revision History:

--*/

#include "lectouch.h"

#ifdef ALLOC_PRAGMA
    #pragma alloc_text( INIT, DriverEntry )
    #pragma alloc_text( PAGE, HidFx2EvtDeviceAdd)
    #pragma alloc_text( PAGE, HidFx2EvtDriverContextCleanup)
#endif


NTSTATUS
DriverEntry (
    _in_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject,
    _in_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    )
/*++

Routine Description:

    Installable driver initialization entry point.
    This entry point is called directly by the I/O system.

Arguments:

    DriverObject - pointer to the driver object

    RegistryPath - pointer to a unicode string representing the path,
                   to driver-specific key in the registry.

Return Value:

    STATUS_SUCCESS if successful,
    STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL otherwise.

--*/
{
    NTSTATUS               status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG      config;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  attributes;

    //
    // Initialize WPP Tracing
    //
    //WPP_INIT_TRACING( DriverObject, RegistryPath );

    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, HidFx2EvtDeviceAdd);

    //
    // Register a cleanup callback so that we can call WPP_CLEANUP when
    // the framework driver object is deleted during driver unload.
    //
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&attributes);
    //attributes.EvtCleanupCallback = HidFx2EvtDriverContextCleanup;

    //
    // Create a framework driver object to represent our driver.
    //
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
                             RegistryPath,
                             &attributes,      // Driver Attributes
                             &config,          // Driver Config Info
                             WDF_NO_HANDLE
                             );

    //if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    //    WPP_CLEANUP(DriverObject);
    //}

    return status;
}


NTSTATUS
HidFx2EvtDeviceAdd(
    IN WDFDRIVER       Driver,
    IN PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
    )
/*++
Routine Description:

    HidFx2EvtDeviceAdd is called by the framework in response to AddDevice
    call from the PnP manager. We create and initialize a WDF device object to
    represent a new instance of toaster device.

Arguments:

    Driver - Handle to a framework driver object created in DriverEntry

    DeviceInit - Pointer to a framework-allocated WDFDEVICE_INIT structure.

Return Value:

    NTSTATUS

--*/
{
    NTSTATUS                      status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG           queueConfig;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES         attributes;
    WDFDEVICE                     hDevice;
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION             devContext = NULL;
    WDFQUEUE                      queue;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    PAGED_CODE();

    //
    // Tell framework this is a filter driver. Filter drivers by default are  
    // not power policy owners. This works well for this driver because
    // HIDclass driver is the power policy owner for HID minidrivers.
    //
    WdfFdoInitSetFilter(DeviceInit);

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_CONTEXT_TYPE(&attributes, DEVICE_EXTENSION);

    //
    // Create a framework device object.This call will in turn create
    // a WDM device object, attach to the lower stack, and set the
    // appropriate flags and attributes.
    //
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, &attributes, &hDevice);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    devContext = GetDeviceContext(hDevice);

    // Figure out where we'll be sending all our requests
    //  once we're done with them
    devContext->TargetToSendRequestsTo = WdfDeviceGetIoTarget(hDevice);

    devContext->LastX = 0;
    devContext->LastY = 0;
    
    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG_INIT_DEFAULT_QUEUE(&queueConfig, WdfIoQueueDispatchParallel);
    queueConfig.EvtIoInternalDeviceControl = HidFx2EvtInternalDeviceControl;

    status = WdfIoQueueCreate(hDevice,
                              &queueConfig,
                              WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
                              &queue
                              );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS (status)) {
        return status;
    }

    return status;
}


VOID
HidFx2EvtDriverContextCleanup(
    IN WDFOBJECT Object
    )
/*++
Routine Description:

    Free resources allocated in DriverEntry that are not automatically
    cleaned up framework.

Arguments:

    Driver - handle to a WDF Driver object.

Return Value:

    VOID.

--*/
{
    PAGED_CODE ();
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Object);

    //WPP_CLEANUP(WdfDriverWdmGetDriverObject((WDFDRIVER) Object));
}
```

Your help in finding the error will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: You are probably missing some headers. Where is `_in_` defined?

Comment: Yeah, I would probably start with grepping for that.

Comment: Arghh!  Thank you - of course that should have been __in